# How to have insert/remove WPF grid row/column in context menu in design mode?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, grid, contextmenu

In the machine at the office my Visual Studio 2010 has the context menu to insert/remove row/colunm from a grid which is very convenient compared to manually insert - requires to update every each of the current row/column indexes.

But at home, my IDE doesn't have this menu. I don't know how to have this context menu `Grid Row` and `Grid Column`.

[image]

### Update

My VS version at home

[image]

My VS version at office

[image]

Answer (score 5):

go to silverlight.net, click the getting started link, and download the latest version of Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio 2010.  This is for the WPF designer too.

Comment: Here's the link http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ you're talking about. I'll have a try on it. Thank you.

Comment: It took me awhile to find the right download, but Silverlight Tools is correct. Here's what worked for me: https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18149

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you might not have the same version of Visual Studio?

Can you compare them? Not just if it's both 2010. In any case: My Premium version at work definately also has it.

Comment: I've update the version of my two IDEs. They look alike. Hope to hear from you.